# python script from cronjob giving error,but not from bash.?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to run a nessus scan from cronjob by subprocess python module. ,but from cronjob it's is giving an error. But not giving any error on execution of script from bash?

the cronjob code

```
01 11 * * * /root/nessusscan.py
```

and subprocess call in script is

```
subprocess.call(['nessus','-q','-x','-T','nessus','127.0.0.1','1241','user','password','ip.txt','res'])
```

from bash it's working fine but from cronjob i am getting following error in mail

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/nessusscan.py", line 9, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['nessus','-q','-x','-T','nessus','127.0.0.1','1241','user','password','ip.txt','res'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: Probably the cron job is running as a different user? See [this answer thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598530/cron-job-and-folders-permissions-permission-denied) for some ideas.

Comment: @Bo102010 not actully... it is running as root.... i mean i am signed in from root user....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thnx to evry one i am answering my own question for other people who will vist this thread. So that they can also get out of this error. In my case error got solved by giving the path of nessus which is `"/opt/nessus/bin/nessus"`

replaced `nessus` with `"/opt/nessus/bin/nessus"`

cronjob was not able to get the path of nessus command.It's working now.